# CMake Install A Generated Artifact Next To Source

Tags: cmake

How can I get the location of an arbitrary target at *install*-time?

```cmake
install(
  FILES ${target}.artifact
  DESTINATION "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${target}>/target.artifact"
)
```

does not work, as `TARGET_FILE_DIR` returns the *build*-time location of `target`.

---

I have a function adding a custom command to generate an artifact (let's call it `${target}.artifact`) at build-time:

```cmake
function(make_artifact target)
  add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${target} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ...
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${target}>"
    DEPENDS ${target}
  )
endfunction()
```

This artifact is placed directly next to the input target. I.e.

```
my_proj
| - build
    | - bin
        | - my_bin_target
        | - my_bin_target.artifact # created after building
    | - lib
        | - my_lib_target
        | - my_lib_target.artifact # created after building
```

I would like to install `my_target` inside my function. The installation should ensure that `my_target.artifact` is placed next to wherever `my_target` ends up -- wherever that may be. So

```cmake
function(make_artifact target)
  add_custom_command(...)
  install(
    FILES path/to/${target}.artifact
    DESTINATION # ???????????????
  )
endfunction()
```

How do I do this?

Comment: "The installation should ensure that my_target.artifact is placed next to wherever my_target ends up" - Take value of DESTINATION option when install `my_target` and copy it to the DESTINATION option when install additional files. In CMake a target doesn't remember the path where it is installed (and a target can be installed several times). If your `install(TARGET)` invocation doesn't specify DESTINATION option, then it uses appropriate `CMAKE_INSTALL_*` variable, see the table of such variables in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-targets).